# How to set up SSL for ELB to E2C in private subnet of VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, https

I can't seem to find any documentation that deals with this scenario in a VPC.

- I have an EC2 in a private subnet.
- I have an internet facing ELB in a public subnet
- ELB has SSL cert and accepts https connections

What are the steps to set up https communication between ELB and EC2?  If https is terminated at ELB do i need to set up certs for ELB > EC2?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turns out this setting is on the ELB but you only see it on creation.  Once the ELB has been created it's no longer visible.

When creating the ELB you need to select 'Backend Authentication' and then you have the option there to upload your SSL certs.  If the SSL is incorrect for whatever reason than any secure health checks will fail.

Under this scenario SSL is terminated on the ELB and then the ELB initiates a new SSL connection with the backend servers.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see how this is any different from any other ELB setup. The fact that the EC2 instance is in a private subnet has no bearing on the SSL certificate.

If you want communication between the ELB and the EC2 instance to use SSL, then you would need to install an SSL certificate on the EC2 instance. How you do that depends entirely on what web server or other server software you are running on the EC2 instance.

> If https is terminated at ELB do i need to set up certs for ELB > EC2?

If you only care about securing communication from the internet into your VPC, then no you don't need this. If you care about securing the communication within your VPC then you would need this. I'm having trouble thinking of a reason that you would care about that, since the communication between the ELB and the EC2 instance is entirely contained within your VPC.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't you just terminate the SSL on the ELB and then use the ELB itself to choose which underlying web server traffic is routed to (via Http)?

If that's in a private subnet (which it should be) then you,ll have needed to set up the route tables / NACLs and security groups accordingly (which you would need to do anyway) to ensure the http traffic can be routed accordingly inbound and outbound